# Android MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener - Percentage of buffered content is negative

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, buffering

I have a service that uses `MediaPlayer` to stream internet radio:

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service implements 
    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener {

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private WifiLock mWifiLock;

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MY_URL);

        // Acquire CPU lock and wi-fi lock

        mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mWifiLock = ((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
             .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "Media Player Wi-Fi Lock");
        mWifiLock.acquire();

        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        Log.d("Buffered " + percent);
    }
}
```

Everything works great except `onBufferingUpdate(...)` method. It prints this in the log:

```
Buffered -819200000 
Buffered -819200000 
Buffered -1228800000 
Buffered -1228800000 
Buffered -1228800000 
Buffered -1228800000 
Buffered -1638400000 
Buffered -1638400000 
Buffered -1638400000 
Buffered -1638400000 
Buffered -2048000000 
Buffered -2048000000 
Buffered -2048000000 
Buffered -2048000000 
Buffered -2147483648 (repeated further on)
```

> Note: -2147483648 is Integer MIN_VALUE

While `percent` is supposed to be:

> The percentage (0-100) of the content that has been buffered or played
>   thus far

**Questions**:

1. Why incorrect values are passed in `onBufferingUpdate()` `percent` parameter?
2. How to fix that?
3. Is there any other way to get how much data has been buffered? My goal is to show a progress bar to give user an idea of when enough data will be buffered and radio playback will start.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why is this happening, I had the same problem, but this code may help you:

```
@Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (percent < 0 || percent > 100) {
                    //System.out.println("Doing math: (" + (Math.abs(percent)-1)*100.0 + " / " +Integer.MAX_VALUE+ ")" );
                    percent = (int) Math.round((((Math.abs(percent)-1)*100.0/Integer.MAX_VALUE)));

                }
                progressBar.setProgress(percent);
                Log.i("Buffering! " , " " +percent );
                System.out.println("Buffering: " +percent);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) 
{
    double ratio = percent / 100.0;
    bufferingLevel = (int)(mp.getDuration() * ratio);

    seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(bufferingLevel);
}
```

And somewhere upper in `OnCreateView` OR `OnCreate`

```
seekBar.setMax(GET_TOTAL_DURATION_OF_SONG);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it this week. However, I'm not sure how it will solve the problem with `percent` having values I mentioned in the question.

Comment: have you checked the URL of the music ?

Comment: What would you suggest to look for? The URL is working as far as audio playback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Android Player Driver, point is in signed/unsigned values. Here is related [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65564).

To solve it on JVM level you can use this code:

```
percent &= 0xFF;
// media broadcasts may return values more than 100
if (percent > 100)
    percent = 0;
```

Comment: Interesting! I will try it today. Thanks!